# How to append new data to array stored on firebase's firestore? Node, Ionic3, Angular,Javascript

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3

Need some help. I am unable to access `arrayUnion` or `FieldValue` from `firebase.firestore`. I have array of maps stored on firestore. I need to append data in same array with increment in index even `{merge:true}` is not working. I am using Ionic 3.

`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion` - getting error at arrayUnion.

The error is:

```
Property 'arrayUnion' does not exist on type 'typeof FieldValue'
```

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to see the code you're having difficulty with in order to assist. Also include your troubleshooting and also a image of your Firebase structure so we know what you're attempting to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN CASE SOMEONE IS HAVING SAME PROBLEM.
arrayUnion method is in firebase v5.3.0 and above.
It also consists of so many array operation methods. Just update firebase by     npm firebase@latest